# php database queries in foreach and optimization

Tags: php, database

I am creating a multilingual website and I want to display a different data for each country.

So i already had created script which determines the language and origin of the user and I need to load data from 3 databases on the website in foreach function.

I had 3 database
listFrom, listFromCountryCode, listFromLang

```
listFrom:
id, prefix, status
 
listFromCountryCode:
id, idList, countryCode, status,
 
listFromTranslate:
id, idList, name, langCode, status
```

currently, to get this data I need to do a loop for listFromCountryCode and listFrom to get prefix. I came up with some optimizations such as use INNER JOIN in query. I cant connect these database in one piece because prefix for other countries is the same. I haven't done this code yet because at the beginning I wanted to ask more experienced developers for advice on how to optimize it. I know that the use of a loop for database queries is bad but I have no idea for another solution.

**Update**

Already created script and time-tested so when in table is more elements (100) site loaded in 3s. Normal script without that script loaded in 0.46s. Anyone got any idea how to optimize this script?

```
    public function checkCountryCodeList()
    {
        $sql      = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listFromCountryCode WHERE countryCode = :code AND status = :status";
        $array  = array(':code' => $this->countryCode, ':status' => $this->status);
        $result = $this->db->selectCount($sql, $array);

        if($result > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getCountryCodeList()
    {
        $sql      = "SELECT idList
                             FROM listFromCountryCode 
                             WHERE countryCode = :code";
        $array  = array(':code' => $this->countryCode);
        $result = $this->db->select($sql, $array);  

        return $result;
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        if(!$this->checkCountryCodeList()){
            $this->countryCode = DEFAULT_COUNTRYCODE;
        }

        $countryCodeList = $this->getCountryCodeList(); 
        $data                    = array();

        foreach($countryCodeList as $row){
            $sql        = "SELECT listFrom.prefix, listFromTranslation.name 
                                 FROM listFrom, listFromTranslation
                                 WHERE listFrom.id = listFromTranslation.idList 
                                 AND listFrom.id = :id
                                 And listFromTranslation.langCode = :code";

            $array  = array(
                ':id'   => $row['idList'],
                ':code' => $this->langCode
            );
        
            $result = $this->db->select($sql, $array);


            $data[] = ['name' => $result[0]['name'], 'prefix' => $result[0]['prefix']];
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

**Update**
Some example data

```
listFrom

| id | prefix |status |
|--- | ------ |-------|
| 1  | btc    |1      |
| 2  | psc    |1      |

listFromCountryCode

| id | idList |countryCode |status |
|--- | ------ |------------|------ |
| 1  | 1      |de          |1      |
| 2  | 2      |de          |1      |

listFromTranslate

| id | idList| name        |langCode |status |
|--- | ------| ----------- |---------|------ |
| 1  | 1     | bitcoin     |en       |1      |
| 2  | 2     | paysafecard |en       |1      |
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking about here? Optimizing the query or the database structure? Either of those two would need more details. Side note: you say `database`, but what you really mean is `table`.

Comment: I asking for optimizing executing php script with foreach while or any other good idea to solve this problem. because if these records are many, the script will take a long time to load

Comment: I think you're optimizing a little early. Write the query and only if it is actually too slow, look for ways to optimize.

Comment: Yeah i know but i'm afraid there will be more results for these lists and that the query loop would not be a very good solution

Comment: I understand your fears, but trust me, you shouldn't worry about it now. Make it work first, then look for potential optimizations. Besides, it will be much easier for anyone to give you optimization advice once you can present a concrete situation.

Comment: okay i made this script and updated thread

Comment: Now things are clearer. This really should be just one `JOIN` to fetch all the data. Can you provide your table structure and some sample data as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)?

Comment: Sure, thread updated